# How to find decimal value of 128 bit number ( 2 - 64 bit long long) from 2 64 bit represented number?

Tags: c++, hex, number-formatting

I want to find the decimal value of an 128 bit number. The 128 bit number has high part and low part and represented as UINT64. I want to know which methods can I use it to see the number in the console, I am using C++. printf and cout both OK:
Only method comes to my mind is iterating over 128 times and calculating each bits decimal value and fit into a 3- 64 byte number.

I tried to search different methods but could not find any.

edit: portability is not concern.

```
UINT64 a = 0x0000000000000001;
UINT64 b = 0x1000000000000001;
// some printing
// result is 18446744073709551618.
```

Comment: The simplest answer is to use a third party library that handles multi precision arithmetic. GMP and MPIR are both freely available, and both could convert a 128 bit number into an equivalent decimal string.

Comment: Or, if portability is not a concern, use a 128-bit type available to you.

Comment: Your edit makes the question self-contradictory. It suggests you want `0x0000000000000001 + 0x1000000000000001`, which is `18446744073709551618`. But the rest of the question suggests you want  `0x00000000000000011000000000000001`, (which is `19599665578316398593`) or `0x10000000000000010000000000000001` (which is `21267647932558653984907657038195064833`). Which of these three do you want?

Comment: Re "*portability is not concern.*", Then what compiler, OS and CPU are you targeting?